# Pass the value of a dropdown list to a Javascript variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

How do you get a drop down list to control the value of a Javascript variable?

I'm trying to give the option of filtering a table by year, and I want this dropdownlist to change the value of a Javascript variable called yearVariable.

My code:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("yearVariable", Model.myArray, new { onchange =javascript:ReloadTable()" })%>
```

(as you can see, the dropdownlist is created using HTML Helper, getting its values from an array; also I don't want to have to click a submit button.)
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any specific javascript framework or just plain javascript?

Comment: MVC. Actually I've kind of worked it out:
<%=Html.DropDownList("yearFilter", Model.PossibleYears, new { onchange = "javascript:ReloadTable(this.value)" })%>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply just missing a quote in your original code:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList(
    "yearVariable", 
    Model.myArray, 
    new { onchange = "javascript:ReloadTable()" })%>
```